# Map-Reduce count number of documents in each minute MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, statistics

I have a MongoDB collection which has a `created_at` stored in each document. These are stored as a MongoDB date object e.g.

```
{ "_id" : "4cacda7eed607e095201df00", "created_at" : "Wed Oct 06 2010 21:22:23 GMT+0100 (BST)", text: "something" }
{ "_id" : "4cacdf31ed607e0952031b70", "created_at" : "Wed Oct 06 2010 21:23:42 GMT+0100     (BST)", text: "something" }
....
```

I would like to count the number of items created between each minute, so I can pass the data into Google Charts to generate something like this:

[image]

How do I do this with a map reduce function, or is there a fancy MongoDB aggregate function which I could use instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map function should emit a timestamp object, adjusted up to the minute, and a count of 1. The reduce function should sum all the counts:

```
map = function() {
    var created_at_minute = new Date(this.created_at.getFullYear(),
                                     this.created_at.getMonth(), 
                                     this.created_at.getDate(), 
                                     this.created_at.getHours(), 
                                     this.created_at.getMinutes());
    emit(created_at_minute, {count: 1});
}

reduce = function(key, values) { 
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
        total += values[i].count; 
    }
    return {count: total};
}
```

Comment: http://pastebin.me/51e1e0f24cb174991ebd9072f1d9bbec -- Tested with some rough testdata, seems to be doing what the poster intended... +1

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [group](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Group) function.

```
db.stat.group({key:{"create_at_minute":true}
              ,initial:{count:0}
              ,reduce:function(doc,out){out.count++}})
```

where create_at_minute is your create_at field rounded by minutes.

Comment: Where does create_at_minute come from, does mongodb figure it out when I run that query?

Comment: .group() is an easier way to achieve aggregation, however it has limitations. The BSON object returned must be small, with less than 10K keys, otherwise you get an exception.

Comment: Tom, i'm a little fib. The "key" in .group() must be in collection. so the solution by rubayeet is more correct and general.

Comment: ah, if the limit is 10k then I'm out of luck my dataset is already at 38k. Thanks, group looks interesting for other datasets.