# MongoDB count number of new documents per minute based on _id

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I want to create a statistic on how many new documents are stored each minute.

Since the _id field with standard ObjectID contains already the timestamp of the document creation I think it should be possible to somehow use it.

On Stackoverflow i found the following map reduce code to get it done when there is a dedicated field for the creation data

[Map-Reduce count number of documents in each minute MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879371/map-reduce-count-number-of-documents-in-each-minute-mongodb)

```
map = function() {

var created_at_minute = new Date(this.created_at.getFullYear(),
                                 this.created_at.getMonth(), 
                                 this.created_at.getDate(), 
                                 this.created_at.getHours(), 
                                 this.created_at.getMinutes());
    emit(created_at_minute, {count: 1});
}

reduce = function(key, values) { 
         var total = 0;
         for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { total += values[i].count; }
         return {count: total};
}
```

According to the Mongo DB Documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) it should be possible to get the timestamp from the _id by calling ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea").getTimestamp().

Right now I have no idea if it is possible at all to use this getTimestamp() inside of the map function.

Has anybody an idea how to do it or is there a better way ?

I need it to be implementable in python or php

Comment: The map function must be written in JavaScript. I'm not sure what you mean "it must be implementable in python or php"? If the `_id` is an ObjectId, then per the docs, `getTimestamp` should work fine. I don't understand why you haven't tried it?

Comment: The map reduce is written in javaskiprt i know but that has to be executable via php or python... I am trying right now to get something done but i am pretty new to map reduce via mongodb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with M/R indeed. `getTimestamp()` works in M/R as it runs in JavaScript on the server, it doesn't matter whether your client language is PHP or Python:

```
map = function() {
    var datetime = this._id.getTimestamp();

    var created_at_minute = new Date(datetime.getFullYear(),
                                     datetime.getMonth(),
                                     datetime.getDate(),
                                     datetime.getHours(),
                                     datetime.getMinutes());
    emit(created_at_minute, {count: 1});
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { total += values[i].count; }
    return {count: total};
}

db.so.mapReduce( map, reduce, { out: 'inline' } );
db.inline.find();
```

Which outputs something like:

```
{ "_id" : ISODate("2013-08-05T15:24:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 9 } }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2013-08-05T15:26:00Z"), "value" : { "count" : 2 } }
```

However, I would suggest you **don't use M/R** but instead turn to the aggregation framework as it's much faster because can use indexes and run concurrently. Right now, the A/F does not have an operator to get the timestamp out of an `ObjectID` field yet though so you *will* have to store the time at the moment of insertion as well. F.e. with documents like this:

```
db.so.drop();
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:15" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:19" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:25" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:32" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:24:45" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:25:15" ) } );
db.so.insert( { date: new ISODate( "2013-08-05T15:25:15" ) } );

db.so.aggregate( [
    { $group: {
        _id: {
            y: { '$year': '$date' },
            m: { '$month': '$date' },
            d: { '$dayOfMonth': '$date' },
            h: { '$hour': '$date' },
            i: { '$minute': '$date' },
        },
        count: { $sum : 1 }
    } } 
] );
```

Which outputs:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "y" : 2013,
                "m" : 8,
                "d" : 5,
                "h" : 15,
                "i" : 25
            },
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "y" : 2013,
                "m" : 8,
                "d" : 5,
                "h" : 15,
                "i" : 24
            },
            "count" : 5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: thx very much , i think you might be right with using the aggregation framework, the map reduce does not seem to be a killer with mongo db right now. only disadvantage i have to store the insertion time "manually"...

Comment: maybe it is somehow possible to extract the timestamp from _id in a working step before applying the aggregation framework.

So like where no date exsists, extract _id.getTimestamp and update document 

Apply Aggregation Framwork

Comment: do you know how to get the date from a subdocument "metadata.timestamp" i tried  {$project : {timestamp : "$metadata.timestamp"}},

Comment: Jep it works, didnt select the right collection in the shell ;) Now i have to think about how to store the results, so that i can save time in generation a new statistic each time